# How can I open .rar archives in lubuntu's built-in file manager?

Tags: lubuntu, archive, pcmanfm, rar

**Lubuntu 18.04.1** includes the lightweight but surprisingly powerful GUI file manager **PCManFM 1.2.5**, which can list the files within a .rar, but fails to extract or display them. Error messages (e.g. *Huffman coding error*) imply an inability to decode the main body of the .rar, though its directory is readable.

Comment: Did you have installed `rar` and `unrar` packages?

Comment: @N0rbert: Please see my own answer, below ;-)
(It's tricky to post both halves of a Q&A simultaneously...)

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal (named **LXTerminal** in *lubuntu*), enter the command

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

and follow the instructions. **PCManFM** should now handle .rar archives just like normal directories.

Note that the **unrar** unpacker is free of charge, even though all packages able to create .rar archives require buying a licence.